# Can't use a ValueTuple with more than 4 elements as ASP.NET MVC model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, c#-7.0, valuetuple

I'm trying to use a C# 7 ValueTuple as the model for a partial view. It works fine when I use a 4-tuple:

```
@model System.ValueTuple<string, string, int, int>
```

But if I try to use a 5-tuple:

```
@model System.ValueTuple<string, string, int, int, string>
```

I get a compilation error:

```
 Compiler Error Message: CS1003: Syntax error, ',' expected
```

When I look at the generated code under "Temporary ASP.NET Files", I think I see the issue:

```
    public class _Page_Views_Reports_TestResultComparison_cshtml : System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage<System.ValueTuple<string {
```

Specifically, the ValueTuple gets cut off (which is why I think the compiler is complaining about a missing ',':

```
System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage<System.ValueTuple<string {
```

Is there a workaround other than creating a separate class? I've tried this using the System.ValueTuple NuGet package under .NET 4.6 as well as switching my project to use .NET 4.7 and I get the same error. I've also set the `system.codedom` `langversion` to `latest`.

Comment: I have checked `@model System.ValueTuple<string, string, int, int, string>` in both ASP.NET Core 2.2 and ASP.NET MVC5 with .NET 4.7.2. It happily compiled.

Comment: Tried it again with a fresh ASP.NET project in VS 15.9.6. The project compiles fine, but when I go to run it I get an error and the generated code still seems to have the same issue: `public class _Page_Views_Home_Index_cshtml : System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage<System.ValueTuple<int {`